# How can I hide downstream connections with my Apple Airport Extreme

Tags: networking, airport

I have an Apple Airport extreme that I'd like to use to extend a network. Is there any way to do this with the upstream hub/router knowing that I have more than one computer connected?

i.e. I want to plut the Airport Extreme into a CAT5 cable from my router. Then share that connection wirelessly. But I don't want the hub to know that there's more than one computer connected as there's a limit to the number of connections.

Thanks
Guy

Comment: Where does the limit come into play?  Is it an ISP thing?

Comment: Your hub would be unware of any devices connnected to your Airport.

Comment: @Ramhound The hub would be aware the same way that carriers detect tethering, namely TTL values. The question is whether or not it's looking for it.